# Calling a function from an external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following:

```
<body>

<script src='script.js'></script>
<script>myFunction()</script>
</body>
```

and inside script.js I had the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    // code to run
}
```

However this is not working for me. and I get the console error that the function is not defined.

Comment: You're not waiting for it to load.

Comment: @c1moore how do I make sure the script.js file is loaded first before the script in the tags executes?

Comment: @c1moore You don't need to wait, `<script>` tags are loaded synchronously.

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery`?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/myhtml.html

Comment: Are you sure it's loading `script.js` successfully? Could you have a typo somewhere? Maybe a difference in capitalization? Do you see the function in the `Sources` tab of the console?

Comment: are you sure script.js is in the same folder of your html file?

Comment: @Barmar because the above is only an example and I am using jQuery, so Im open to answers in jQuery if it provide a solution.

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with the basic operations of loading scripts and running functions. It's a library that you would use inside the function once you get it running.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `<script>` tags in the correct order? You would get this error if you had `<script src="script.js"></script>` second.

Comment: There's really no way to tell what's really going wrong from the little snippet you've shown. You must be doing something different in the actual code.

Comment: @Barmar True.  The OP could confirm the script is loading by looking in the developer console network tab.  If it's loading, he can also confirm that the expected function is defined in the file that is loaded.  The expected function should be defined in the global scope (or somehow accessible from the global scope).